# Shiny - assigning argument to function

Tags: function, shiny, arguments

I am trying to create a shiny app that applies a self-made function to an uploaded dataset, then allows to download the modified results. Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

namkurz <- function(data, a_spalte) {
  kuerzel <- vector(length = length(data$a_spalte))
  for (i in 1:length(data$a_spalte)){
    spez = data$Art[i]
    s = unlist(strsplit(spez, " ", fixed = TRUE))
    s = substr(s, 1, 2)
    s = paste(s, collapse = ' ')
    kuerzel[[i]] = s
  }
  data <- data %>%
    mutate(kurz = kuerzel)
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput('upload','Deine Kartierungsdaten'),
  textInput('art', 'Wie heißt die Spalte mit Artnamen?'),
  downloadButton('analyse','Artenkürzel hinzufügen')
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$upload)
    
    ext <- tools::file_ext(input$upload$name)
    switch(ext,
           csv = vroom::vroom(input$upload$datapath, delim = ";"),
           validate("Invalid file; Please upload a .csv file")
    )
  })
  art <- reactive(input$art)
  output$analyse <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0('mit_kuerzel', ".csv")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      ergebnis <- reactive(namkurz(data(), art()))
      vroom::vroom_write(ergebnis(), file)
    }
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When trying to save the output I get a 'Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column:' error. I think my problem is in the assignment of argument 'art' to the 'ergebnis' object, but I can't find the way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a few things:

1. (Required) In your function, `a_spalte` is a character vector and not the literal name of column in the frame, so you need to use `[[` instead of `$`, see [The difference between bracket [ ] and double bracket [[ ]] for accessing the elements of a list or dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/3358272) and [Dynamically select data frame columns using $ and a character value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18222286/3358272).

   Change all references of `data$a_spalte` to `data[[a_spalte]]`.

   ```r
   namkurz <- function(data, a_spalte) {
     kuerzel <- vector(length = length(data[[a_spalte]]))
     for (i in 1:length(data[[a_spalte]])){
       spez = data$Art[i]
       s = unlist(strsplit(spez, " ", fixed = TRUE))
       s = substr(s, 1, 2)
       s = paste(s, collapse = ' ')
       kuerzel[[i]] = s
     }
     data <- data %>%
       mutate(kurz = kuerzel)
   }
   ```
2. Your function is a bit inefficient doing things row-wise, we can vectorize that operation.

   ```r
   namkurz <- function(data, a_spalte) {
     spez <- strsplit(data$Art, " ", fixed = TRUE)
     data$kurz <- sapply(spez, function(z) paste(substr(z, 1, 2), collapse = " "))
     data
   }
   ```
3. (Optional) The `content=` portion of `downloadHandler` is already reactive, you do not need to wrap `namkurz` in `reactive`. Because of this, you also don't need to treat `ergebnis` as reactive.

   ```r
     output$analyse <- downloadHandler(
       filename = ...,
       content = function(file) {
         ergebnis <- namkurz(data(), art())
         vroom::vroom_write(ergebnis, file)
       }
     )
   ```
4. (Optional) Your output filename is fixed, so two things here: if it's always going to be `"mit_kuerzel.csv"`, then there's no need for `paste0`, just use `function() "mit_kuerzel.csv"`.

   However, if you are intending to return a file named something based on the original input filename, one could do something like:

   ```r
       filename = function() {
     paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(input$upload$name)),
            "_mit_kuerzel.",
            tools::file_ext(input$upload$name))
       },
   ```

   to add `_mit_kuerzel` to the base portion of the uploaded filename. Note that the `file` in the `content=` section is never this name, the `new_mit_kuerzel.csv` is the filename offered to the downloading browser as a suggestion, that is all.
5. (Optional) You are using a `.csv` file extension in the `downloadHandler`, but the default for `vroom::vroom_write` is to use `delim = "\t"`, which is not a CSV. I suggest either adding `delim = ";"` (or similar), or changing the returned filename extension to `.tsv` instead.